# Select The last 3 news from each category - Two tables - (MySQL - PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to select the last 3 news from each category, from two table

```
first table ' Categories ' & ' news '
```

categories table

```
ID_CAT | NAME | PRIORITE
```

News table

```
ID | ID_CAT | TITLE | THE_NEWS
```

I try to do limit in this SQL code, but it gives me just the last 3 news from all categories

```
SELECT C.PRIORITE, N.* 
  FROM categories C, news N 
 WHERE N.ID_CAT=C.ID_CAT 
   AND C.PRIORITE >1 
ORDER BY N.ID DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

I try to get all news that have `PRIORITE > 1` ( The priorite is the order of category ) So, I want to get 3 last news from each priorite.

Example :

```
Priorite 2 = get last 3 news
Priorite 3 = get last 3 news
```

... etc

I made some search on the internet, but nothing worked for me, is there any solution? Or do I need to create another function to get news from each category with ID sending in parameters of it?

Comment: To help on a query question, we need to see: tables with columns and types, sample data for input, what output you want, what output you are getting with the query you have right now.

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks for your reply sir, I modified the post

Comment: My instinct would be to chuck it in a foreach($categories as $category) loop but that could/would eventually be rather intensive and long. There's probably a way to do it with subqueries that may be quicker. As far as I'm aware the "best" way would be to have an "all" page and then "category" pages to circumvent this.

Comment: @Joshua thanks for your reply sir, I avoid to make another function because that can make the response longer, for that I want to make a simple query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get n no. of news for each category by using a correlated sub query

```
SELECT *
FROM news n
JOIN categories c ON c.id = n.category_id
WHERE c.priority > 1
AND (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM news 
  WHERE n.category_id = category_id
  AND n.id <= id
) <= 3;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6ed5Mu7rFCQEQc6DpG7RTW/0)

Or if you are using Mysql 8 then you could make use of [**window functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) with [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) like

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY id DESC ) rnk
    FROM news
    ORDER BY id

)

SELECT *
FROM cte n
JOIN categories c ON c.id = n.category_id
WHERE c.priority > 1
AND rnk <= 3;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c8D5Q2g5Wcy2i42WYzS18H/1)

Answer (score 2):

i suggest divide it 2 parts, instead of complex query,

in 1st part you can get categories

```
select * from Categories
```

then loop categories and in loop get their 3 news,

```
select * from news where cat_id = '' order by desc id limit 3
```

if you try both and check the execution time, you see loop take less time. because news are rapidly growing stuff. i know you think why i call query again and again but my teacher said prefer multiple queries instead of complex one

Comment: This may end up on [Performance: N+1 Query Problem](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it should work:

```
SELECT
    C.PRIORITE, N.*
FROM
    categories C
JOIN news N ON N.ID_CAT=C.ID_CAT
AND C.PRIORITE >1 
GROUP BY
    C.ID_CAT
HAVING
    COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY N.ID DESC
```

Lemme know if there's any problem with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I try it and the result is zero rows

Comment: I see you changed your column name to ID_CAT, I hope that wasn't the issue. I updated the query above. Try that once.

Comment: No sir is not the issue because I edited after trying the query, when I drop this line `HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3` the result is one row of each category

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. This query generate a row number for each record based on the PRIORITE. Then return row number equal or less than 3.

```
SELECT ID, PRIORITE, THE_NEWS
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, PRIORITE, THE_NEWS  ,
   @rn := IF(@prior = PRIORITE, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
   @prior := PRIORITE 
   FROM(
   SELECT t.*,c.PRIORITE FROM news t 
   LEFT JOIN categories c ON t.ID_CAT=c.ID_CAT ) e
   CROSS JOIN (select @rn:=0, @prior:=null) c
   ORDER BY  PRIORITE,ID desc
) as x 
WHERE x.rn <= 3 ;
```